# What is the maximum number of columns allowed on a table in MySQL MEMORY storage engine?

Tags: mysql

The official MySQL documentation the the MEMORY storage engine covers maximum table size (in MB) but the maximum number of columns that can be defined on a table is not specified.

This question is specifically about the MEMORY storage engine - not InnoDB or MySQL in general.

Comment: If you need more than a hundred columns, you should rethink the architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [This MySQL link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-count-limit.html)

> There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective
>   maximum may be less for a given table. The exact limit depends on
>   several interacting factors.
>
> - Every table (regardless of storage engine) has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes. Storage engines may place additional constraints on this limit, reducing the effective maximum row size.
>
> ...

These are engine-independent MySQL limits. As you say the MEMORY engine specific manual pages do not seem to specify any additional restrictions for size or count.

Comment: OK, that seems like a reasonable assumption so I have marked this as the answer. It would be great to know for sure though.